# In R is there a way to color a phytools tree based on a vector of factors from a data frame?

Tags: r

I have a tree with 18 tips that looks like this;

```
library(phytools)
# Create tree
sim.tree<-pbtree(n=18)
plot(sim.tree)
```

Then I have a data frame with the tip name and a vector of factors I would like to use to color the tree with, like;

```
df<-data.frame(tip = paste0("t", 1:18),
               vector.to.color.with = as.factor(c("<10", "10-20", "10-20", "10-20", "NA", "10-20", 
                                   "10-20", "10-20", "20-35", "<10", "10-20", "<10", 
                                   "35", "20-35", "<10", "NA", "10-20", "<10")))
```

I have tried using `tip.color()` and `plotBranchbyTrait()` to no avail. I know this is probably done all the time and I am missing something simple. Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check `?plot.phylo`

```r
library(phytools)
# Create tree
df<-data.frame(tip = paste0("t", 1:18),
               vector.to.color.with = as.factor(c("<10", "10-20", "10-20", "10-20", "NA", "10-20", 
                                                  "10-20", "10-20", "20-35", "<10", "10-20", "<10", 
                                                  "35", "20-35", "<10", "NA", "10-20", "<10")))
set.seed(123)
sim.tree<-pbtree(n=18)
cols <- as.integer(df$vector.to.color.with[match(sim.tree$tip.label,df$tip)])
plot(sim.tree, tip.color = cols)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Stefano Barbi. This does color the tree, but it is not matched to the tip name. For example, t13 is the only tip with a factor of "35" and should therefore be the only tip with that color. Maybe I am missing the link between the tree and the vector? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Dustin You're right. Funny thing is that I checked another tree (no seed) and by chance the colors I checked were matching. Now it should work.

Comment: Thank you @Stefano Barbi! This worked on my real data as well!

Comment: Thanks again @Stefano Barbi ! I have taken this to the next level if it interests you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71610843/in-r-when-coloring-a-phylogenetic-tree-by-a-trait-using-tip-color-how-do-you